# How to get lease on Azure storage file?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-cloud-services, azure-storage-files

I have multi instance web application in azure cloud. I want to make sure that only one of them read and process file from azure storage file. I thought using lease option I can make it happen.

However I am unable to find proper methods for this operation. I found this [REST API option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/lease-file) but I am looking for something [like this.](https://alexandrebrisebois.wordpress.com/2013/09/08/dont-be-fooled-blob-lease-management-is-tricky-business/)

This example shows for blob storage. What are file storage options? I am using latest file storage nuget.

EDIT:

This is how I am getting data from storage file and processing the data.

```
    var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("FileStorageConnectionString");
    var fileClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudFileClient();
    var share = fileClient.GetShareReference("StorageFileShareName");
    var file = this.share.GetRootDirectoryReference().GetFileReference("file.txt");
---processing file and renaming the file after processing---
```

How to implement lease on this file so that no other cloud instance get the access to this file? After processing the file I will also rename it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try something like below:

```
        string connectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=<account-name>;AccountKey=<account-key>;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net;";
        var shareClient = new ShareClient(connectionString, "test");
        shareClient.CreateIfNotExists();
        var fileClient = shareClient.GetRootDirectoryClient().GetFileClient("test.txt");
        var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("This is a test");
        fileClient.Create(bytes.Length);
        fileClient.Upload(new MemoryStream(bytes));
        var leaseClient = fileClient.GetShareLeaseClient();
        Console.WriteLine("Acquiring lease...");
        var leaseId = leaseClient.Acquire();
        Console.WriteLine("Lease Id: " + leaseId);
        Console.WriteLine("Breaking lease...");
        leaseClient.Break();
        Console.WriteLine("Lease broken...");
```

It makes use of [`Azure.Storage.Files.Shares`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Storage.Files.Shares/12.2.0) Nuget package.

Comment: I am accessing the file using CloudFileClient instance and able to get the data and process it. Why cant I get the lease that way? Added code for reference in my original question.

Comment: `CloudFileClient` is part of the older SDK which targets an older REST API version whereas `File Lease` functionality is announced in the new REST API version. This is the reason why you can't use CloudFileClient.

Comment: My application targets .NET4.6.2 and I am using Microsoft.Azure.Storage.File 11.1.3 version. Instead of this I should Storage.Files.Shares package to read and lease Azure storage file?

Comment: Hang on a second. Let me take a look at Microsoft.Azure.Storage.File 11.1.3 package. That should have support for leasing files according to this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/protocol-version-support-for-.net-client-library-versions.

Comment: I looked at this SDK and unfortunately could not find any lease related information in there. You may want to open up an issue here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/issues. SDK version 11 and 12 are drastically different so you must evaluate if upgrading SDK version just to acquire lease would make sense for you or not.

Comment: Other alternative could be to simply create a SAS URL on the file and consume the REST API directly.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Upgrading to 12 is no problem for us as long as we dont need to change framework version(NET462). Good to know SAS option also. So if we go for SDK 12 I should use Storage.Files.Shares package right?

Comment: For SDK version 12, yes. Here's the link: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Storage.Files.Shares.